# Creating variable for argument io into pd.read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

***See [`pandas.read_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).***

---

I am creating a GUI with `Tkinter` that will automate the final scores for several characters. I am also fairly new to `Tkinter`. In my code, I am reading in several excel sheets that will be created into dataframes in order for me to do the appropriate calculations on each. One excel sheet that I will be reading in is an excel sheet that contains a list of characters that users of my code on my team can go in and edit/add new characters if need be. When they run the code, the analysis is updated with any edits/added characters. For this question, I will be using that as an example and call it `filename`.

Ideally, I would like to create a browse button in `Tkinter` that will prompt the user to look for the excel file, then store the selected file in the variable `filename` for future use. My code will have `pd.read_excel()` embedded later, and I would like `filename` to be the excel file /`io` argument that will be read in. **I am just wondering if this is possible. Looking at other attempts doesn't necessarily address what I am looking for either.**

This is also my first time using Tkinter as well, but here's sort of a ***draft*** (emphasis on draft!) of what I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Automation:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Test")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Welcome to the Score Automation.\nPlease select the ALC File containing all updated names.")
        self.label.pack()

        self.browse_button_characterlist = Button(master, text="Select File", command=self.askopenfile)
        self.browse_button_characterlist.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def askopenfile(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        filename = askopenfilename()

        print(filename)

root = Tk()
my_gui = Automation(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Filename is then stored as argument into `pandas.read_excel()`**

```
pd.read_excel(filename, usecols = "B", 
               skiprows = range(0,4), skip_footer = 2)
```

Any suggestions on the ordering or how I utilize `askopenfile()` would also be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear - you know how to get the file name and store it in a variable. What more are you looking to do? Also, your probable want to use `self.filename` to make the file name available to the object after the function call.

Comment: @kabunas edited question body to indicate that I am asking whether if storing a variable into `read_excel()` is possible, and I'm looking for suggestions overall. I do know how to store a variable.

Comment: Why aren't you doing something like `self.excel = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols = "B", 
               skiprows = range(0,4), skip_footer = 2)`?

Comment: currently working on figuring out the placement for this suggested line of code within the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few things here - what an object is, what a module is (and how to extract methods from it if I understand what you tried), and the use of `self`. This is even before `tk` process like the root window. I suggest a tutorial, first in Python, then `tkinter`. to your question, add at the top:

```
#Do not import *, import only what you need.
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```

and change your event handler (I highly recommend changing the name to something that makes sense in your program, i.e. `readExcel`):

```
def askopenfile(self):
    #Force specific file types only. Use `self` to make the file name available from any method.
    self.filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(('xsl','*.xsl'),('xslx','*.xslx')))
    self.excel = pd.read_excel(self.filename, usecols = "B", skiprows = range(0,4), skip_footer = 2)
```

Note I removed the two `Tk()` lines you had - you already have a `Tk` object, in `self.master`. Do not make two as it is unstable and resource heavy, plus there is no reason two (You already have a gui app, why make two?).

You may want to add checks/a try except block to the handler. Both the `filename` and the `excel` members are now available through `self.` in any other method in a `Automation` object.

Comment: I came up with using `filedialog.askopenfilename` then implementing `pd.read_excel()`.